Telegram scam on a plattform called DOMAIN https://www.intercambio329.cc/Trade/tradelist.html
I recently fell through a telegram scam , the person said to transfer cash to a online trading platform called domain .. https://www.intercambio329.cc/Trade/tradelist.html
This is the link of the domain , I had transferred my savings into it , the person then gives me signals whether to buy or sell and I get my profit which is shown in my funding account in that domain platform.
When I wanted to withdraw , usually we enter the bank account and click withdraw ,it usually gets withdrawn and no error usually comes .
But just this time , since the amount is big,  the person is asking me to transfer more amount of money then only he said I can withdraw.
I can still log in and see that my funds are still there in the domain platform,  but whenever I put my bank details and click withdraw ....there is a message always popping " Withdrawal request denied " , is there a way anyone can help me get my funds by breaking there coding or something, I promise I will compensate you with my share.
